# Difference between BufferedWriter and OutputStreamWriter?

Tags: java, performance, memory-efficient

I was Learning about Sockets in java programming . I found BufferedWriter and OutputStreamWriter and i wonder which one of them is more efficient and situations where i can prefer one over the other .

Comment: They offer different functions, look at the doc you will see the different. Choose the one which offers you the most suitable functions.

Answer (score 0):

OutputStreamWriter is Writer adaptor for OutputStream, it creates Writer based on OutputStream.
BufferedWriter is a wrapper on another Writers. It is used for writing with buffer.

So you can use them together.

```
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream));
```